# llvm: dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN4llvm11RuntimeDyld13MemoryManager6anchorEv

Tags: llvm, bazel

I am playing with LLVM and I hit an issue when trying to use JIT. I was able to build a compiler, it can be compiled, linked and it runs correctly (it compiles my toy programs). However, when I am trying to use build a JIT, it fails.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN4llvm11RuntimeDyld13MemoryManager6anchorEv
  Referenced from: /Users/gruszczy/Projects/shwifty/./bazel-bin/_solib_darwin//liblibjit.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/gruszczy/Projects/shwifty/./bazel-bin/_solib_darwin//liblibjit.so
Abort trap: 6
```

I use Bazel to build everything, these are my build rules:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "llvm",
    path = "/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0",
    build_file= "llvm.BUILD")

cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.a"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.*"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    copts = ["-Iexternal/llvm/include"],
)
```

I use JIT in tests (I generate IR in the test then jit it, then run the method to see if it worked).

```
cc_library(
    name = "jit",
    srcs = ["jit.cc"],
    hdrs = ["jit.h"],
    deps = [
        ":ast",
        ":common",
        "@llvm//:main"
    ],
    copts = GENERAL_COPTS)

cc_test(
    name = "codegen_test",
    srcs = ["codegen_test.cc"],
    deps = [
        ":ast",
        ":jit",
        ":lexer",
        ":parser",
        ":codegen",
        "@gtest//:main",
        "@llvm//:main"
    ],
    copts = TEST_COPTS,
    data = [":examples"],
    size = "small"
)
```

Any suggestions what I might be missing?

Comment: In LLVM version installed by brew (Mac OS) this library is called: `libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a`. Depending on your distribution of LLVM you need to link it to your program. In your distribution it might be a dynamic library `dylib`, not static library `.a`.

Comment: `/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a` has this library, it should be included in llvm library I create. Are the some additional flags I need to add?

Comment: I don't know what your code is exactly but one reason why that symbol is missing: `__ZN4llvm11RuntimeDyld13MemoryManager6anchorEv` might be that you have to tell linker to `-force_load` all symbols from this library because otherwise it does not see them because you only use them from your JIT code.

Comment: What is your operating system? `-force_load` works on Mac OS, on other systems it might be something else.

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav! I will try to use -force_load, but bazel complains about adding it in linkopts (and I also see a recent commit where they removed force_load).

Comment: `linkopts=["-force_load /opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a",
              "-force_load /opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/libLLVMMCJIT.a"]` works, but is hardly ideal

Comment: At least this confirms the assumption about missing symbols. Another way of doing this is to link what is needed dynamically in runtime right from your code via `dlopen` i.e. LLVM way:  `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::LoadLibraryPermanently("/usr/lib/yourlib.dylib");` (`include 'llvm/support/DynamicLibrary.h`). But for this to work you need to have your libraries built as `dylibs`. Check your build options for LLVM - it might have an option to build libraries as dylibs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of confusion is that Bazel by default links binaries statically, but tests dynamically. This makes the test-code-refactor loop faster, because changes to the test code only trigger the rebuild of the test, not the whole application. It can be disabled by setting `linkstatic = 1` on `codegen_test` target.

As to why the symbols are not present in `codegen_test` when built as a shared library, that's much harder question and would need more project-specific information. But a possible solution might be to mark targets producing `VMRuntimeDyld.a` and `VMMCJit.a` as `alwayslink = 1`.

For the completeness, here's the [link to an issue you reported on bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2944#event-1070269156).